# How to write this SQL query to jOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

```
SELECT 
    feature_name, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
      * cos( radians( long ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) 
      * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM 
    geo_features 
HAVING 
    distance < 25 
ORDER BY 
    distance
```

Comment: Maybe `Query query = create.query("SELECT ...")` like so? There should be helpful info at vendor site of JOOQ - or do I mix this up with something else?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this static import:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Here's how to write your query:

```
GeoFeatures f = Tables.GEO_FEATURES;
Field<Double> distance =
    val(3959.0).mul(acos(cos(rad(37.0)))).mul(cos(rad(f.LAT)))
               .mul(rad(f.LONG).sub(rad(-122.0)).add(sin(rad(37.0)))
               .mul(sin(rad(f.LAT))).as("distance")

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(
       f.FEATURE_NAME,
       distance
   )
   .from(f)
   .having(distance.lt(25.0))
   .orderBy(distance)
```

These are key things to keep in mind:

- Every SQL function translates to a function in [`org.jooq.impl.DSL`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html)
- Arithmetic operations are accessible via "infix" notation, but the operators have to be written as method names, such as `* = mul()`, `+ = add() or plus()`, `- = sub() or minus()`
- Numbers that are on the left hand side of an arithmetic operation have to be wrapped by jOOQ API explicitly, using `val()` (for bind variables) or `inline()` (for inlining)